# Private Blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain

Suppose I create my own private blockchain using Ethereum over the public network means my node is reachable from the internet, now I don't want to share my genesis.json but still want that other can connect with my node to participate in the blockchain. Is it possilbe?

Can other node connect to my node just by mentioning Network ID ? or I need to share them Genesis.json

Answer (score 1):

All nodes on one blockchain must use the same genesis file.  It's like sharing the same radio frequency or speaking the same language.  Even small changes to genesis files can make two nodes unable to communicate.

Not wanting to share the genesis file means you don't really want the other nodes to be peers.  You can't have a peer to peer network without peers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the Genesis.json

To have another node connect to a private Ethereum network,

1. Launch the 2nd peer
2. In the geth JavaScript console of the 2nd peer type `admin.nodeInfo.enode` to get the enode id
3. In the geth JS console of the 1st peer add the enode Id of the 2nd peer
4. You can the verify if the two nodes are communicating using `admin.peers` in the geth JS console

Comment: I have tried this, but I don't connect until I give it same genesis file. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is not true. Each of the nodes have to share the same genesis file for a private network.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have made changes to my answer